# Linear Regression in BigQuery without intercept

Tags: google-bigquery, linear-regression

I am looking over the documentation of BigQuery ML regarding the intercept component in Linear Regression, how to activate or deactivate it, but I cannot find anything. Is there a way to deactivate it? To run a Bigquery LR model without an intercept.

Please note that my intention is not to run a model without an intercept, but rather to include it in the table as constant and then call the BigQuery LR without it adding the intercept.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this training option "fit_intercept" now:
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-ml/docs/reference/standard-sql/bigqueryml-syntax-create-glm#fit_intercept